# jquery animate not working in safari and chrome properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

hi i have a form with some steps. and i animate the step number on each level of registration. my animation is working fine in firefox, but in chrome and safari it is not supporting. it is because of css property `left`. below is my code you can check

Here is html part

```
<div class="steps">
        <p class="step1 active"><b>01</b></p>
        <p class="step2"><b>02</b></p>
        <p class="step3"><b>03</b></p>
        <p class="step4"><b>04</b></p>
        <p class="step5"><b>05</b></p>
    </div>
```

Here is css

```
.steps{
    width:100%;
    height:2px;
    margin:40px 0 0 0;
    background:#f2b913;
    float:left;
    z-index:999999999999999999;
    position:relative;
}

.steps p{
    float:left;
    width:60px;
    position:absolute;
    height:60px;
    border-radius:50%;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:50px;
    color:white;
    background:#FFF;
    padding:2px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    margin:-30px 0 0 0px;
    cursor:pointer;
    border:3px solid #f2b913;
    font-size:20px;
}

.steps p b{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    border-radius:50%;
    background:#f2b913;
}

.steps p:hover b, .steps p.active b{background:#019084;;}

.step1{left:0;}
.step2{left:60px;}
.step3{left:120px;}
.step4{left:180px;}
.step5{left:240px;}
```

and here is jQuery part

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $(".step1").css("left","auto").animate({"right":"0px"}, "slow");
    $(".step2").animate({"left":"0px"}, "slow");
    $(".step3").animate({"left":"60px"}, "slow");
    $(".step4").animate({"left":"120px"}, "slow");
    $(".step5").animate({"left":"180px"}, "slow");
});
```

Comment: isn't this working? http://jsfiddle.net/3X695/

Comment: no. step1 should also animate from left to right. because in css left is 0px and it should change to right:0px

Comment: only problem is it is moving instantly if you check on your local firefox browser you will see actual animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little tweak for the first element:

```
.steps .step1{right: 100%; margin-right: -60px;}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $(".step1").animate({"right":"0px", 'marginRight': 0}, "slow");
    $(".step2").animate({"left":"0px"}, "slow");
    $(".step3").animate({"left":"60px"}, "slow");
    $(".step4").animate({"left":"120px"}, "slow");
    $(".step5").animate({"left":"180px"}, "slow");
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jmR3e/1/)

**Version 2:**

Ok fix for the stupid Safari once again.

```
.steps .step1{ margin-right: 100%; right: -60px;}
```

This is the only change.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jmR3e/3/)

Comment: Added fix for the buggy safari.